# Header doesn't align correctly after running grunt dist

Tags: html, css, sass, gruntjs

I am making a website using the [Yeoman webapp generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp). I have a weird problem. When I just do grunt serve the header items align correctly to the left and right, but when I run grunt dist and open the generated files the header items all align to the left.

My html:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a class="logo" href="index.html"><h1>Title</h1></a>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="blog/">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- endbower -->
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->
        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

My scss file for the header (I am using jeet.gs and breakpoint-sass:

```
header {
  @include center(960px);

  text-align: justify;

  .logo {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  nav {
    ul {
      list-style: none;

      li {
        display: inline-block;

        a {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  a {
    padding: .5em 1em;

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #fff;

    transition: text-decoration .3s ease;

    &:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }

  .logo,
  nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This is the generated css file when using grunt serve:

```
/* line 5, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* line 22, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

/* line 24, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* line 26, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* line 28, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

caption,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* line 30, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

q,
blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}

/* line 103, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

q:before,
q:after,
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

/* line 32, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

a img {
  border: none;
}

/* line 116, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

/*  Syntax Quick Reference
  --------------------------
  column($ratios: 1, $offset: 0, $cycle: 0, $uncycle: 0, $gutter: $jeet-gutter)
  span($ratio: 1, $offset: 0)
  shift($ratios: 0, $col_or_span: column, $gutter: $jeet-gutter)
  unshift()
  edit()
  center($max_width: 1410px, $pad: 0)
  stack($pad: 0, $align: false)
  unstack()
  align($direction: both)
  cf()
*/

/* line 196, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

header,
main .content,
main .content article,
main .content .photo {
  *zoom: 1;
}

/* line 188, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

header:before,
main .content:before,
main .content article:before,
main .content .photo:before,
header:after,
main .content:after,
main .content article:after,
main .content .photo:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

/* line 192, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

header:after,
main .content:after,
main .content article:after,
main .content .photo:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* line 3, ../../app/styles/_base.scss */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* line 9, ../../app/styles/_base.scss */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* line 14, ../../app/styles/_base.scss */

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  background-color: #f77937;
}

/* line 1, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}

/* line 6, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header .logo {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* line 12, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* line 15, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* line 18, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
}

/* line 25, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header a {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: text-decoration .3s ease;
}

/* line 34, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* line 39, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header .logo,
header nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* line 44, ../../app/styles/_header.scss */

header::before,
header::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* line 1, ../../app/styles/_content.scss */

main {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

/* line 5, ../../app/styles/_content.scss */

main .content {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
}

/* line 188, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

main .content:before,
main .content:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

/* line 192, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

main .content:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* line 9, ../../app/styles/_content.scss */

main .content article {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear: none;
  text-align: inherit;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: 65.66667%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  padding: 1em;
}

/* line 41, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

main .content article:last-child {
  margin-right: 0%;
}

/* line 14, ../../app/styles/_content.scss */

main .content article h2 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

/* line 18, ../../app/styles/_content.scss */

main .content article p {
  margin-top: .4em;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* line 9, ../../app/styles/_content.scss */

  main .content article {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  /* line 127, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

  main .content article:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  /* line 130, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

  main .content article:last-child {
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

/* line 27, ../../app/styles/_content.scss */

main .content .photo {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear: none;
  text-align: inherit;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: 31.33333%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  padding: 1em;
}

/* line 41, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

main .content .photo:last-child {
  margin-right: 0%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* line 27, ../../app/styles/_content.scss */

  main .content .photo {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  /* line 127, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

  main .content .photo:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  /* line 130, ../../app/bower_components/jeet.gs/scss/jeet/_grid.scss */

  main .content .photo:last-child {
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

And this is the generated css when using grunt dist (unminified):

```
a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, article, aside, audio, b, big, blockquote, body, canvas, caption, center, cite, code, dd, del, details, dfn, div, dl, dt, em, embed, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html, i, iframe, img, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, mark, menu, nav, object, ol, output, p, pre, q, ruby, s, samp, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, tt, u, ul, var, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, td, th {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 400;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:after, blockquote:before, q:after, q:before {
    content: "";
    content: none;
}
a img {
    border: 0;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
header, main .content, main .content .photo, main .content article {
    *zoom: 1;
}
header:after, header:before, main .content .photo:after, main .content .photo:before, main .content article:after, main .content article:before, main .content:after, main .content:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
header:after, main .content .photo:after, main .content article:after, main .content:after {
    clear: both;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%}
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    letter-spacing: .2px;
    background-color: #f77937;
}
header {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
header .logo {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
}
header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
}
header a {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: text-decoration .3s ease;
}
header a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
header .logo, header nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
header::after, header::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%}
main {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
main .content {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}
main .content:after, main .content:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
main .content:after {
    clear: both;
}
main .content article {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    clear: none;
    text-align: inherit;
    width: 65.66667%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 3%;
    padding: 1em;
}
main .content article:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
main .content article h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
main .content article p {
    margin-top: .4em;
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
    main .content article {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
main .content article:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
main .content article:last-child {
    margin-right: auto;
}
}main .content .photo {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    clear: none;
    text-align: inherit;
    width: 31.33333%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 3%;
    padding: 1em;
}
main .content .photo:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
    main .content .photo {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
main .content .photo:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
main .content .photo:last-child {
    margin-right: auto;
}
}
```

Correct (using grunt serve):
[image: Correct]

Incorrect (using grunt dist):
[image: Incorrect]

So I am not really sure what the problem is... if anyone could help me that would be awesome!

Comment: It takes *all* of this code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I am sorry if it is a bit much, but I don't know where the problem is. So I didn't want to forget anything.

Comment: That's part of the debugging process:  reduce the code to the smallest amount possible to reproduce the problem.  Nine times out of ten, you solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are not floating nav in your header. Use this :

```
header nav{
 float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a problem with `floats`.

Try this floating your first list item to the left, and the others to the right:

```
header nav ul {
    float: left;
}
header nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
header nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
    float: right;
}
```